# Pay access to HTML file

Tags: javascript, paypal, payment, payment-processing

I have a site with a tool on it.  The tool is an HTML form that clients will save a local PDF after filing out.  The form works.  PayPal can be integrated for payment.

All of the code is run on the client side via javascript.  I do NOT want to store any data or credentials on my server.

What I don't understand is how to protect this particular HTML file until someone has paid for it.  I was hoping for maybe a randomized string for the file name that lasts 48 hours or something.  Just not sure what to search for at this point.

The site backend is node.js and using Foundation CSS if that helps.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't protect *anything* once it's at the client.

Comment: A uniquely generated filename, tied to the account, is the common way to handle this.  Then you get so long to download the file.

Comment: I was getting ready to remove the paypal and payment tags because this doesn't seem to have anything to do with either.. but then I thought maybe you were wondering how to get notification when a payment is successful. Is that the case?

Comment: I just want them to pay and then get access to a restricted area on the site temporarily.

Answer (score 2):

If you use a unique/random filename as you mentioned, and have it expire after x amount of time, that will obfuscate, but not protect/secure. Obfuscation is probably more than enough for your needs, but not something that we should be providing as an official StackOverflow answer... so I continue.

It roughly sounds like you have one of those, excuse my wording here, "cheap self-help/how-to/etc pdf for sale that should really be free and probably is somewhere" type of websites. I am sure your product is fantastic and is of the utmost quality, but if you know the sites i'm referring to, and my assumptions are correct, the information below should be helpful.

As far as I understand your needs, you want a version of business logic similar to this:

1. User fills out form on your site
2. User gets redirected to paypal, or is "called to action" with a paypal button.
3. User pays or doesn't pay
4. User downloads/accesses file only if they paid.

**There are a few options you can do:**

*If every user is getting the same file, the below methods should be similar, but simpler*

- Ensure you set the CUSTOM value for whatever PayPal payment method you're using to the unique ID you created for the user, and an email address if you can collect that from them. Then use [PayPal's IPN](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/) to wait until a payment has been received. This IPN notification will have the CUSTOM value for the payment, which is unique per user per payment per file, and you just email them the appropriate file.
- Use [PayPal's Encrypted Website Payments API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/button-manager/BMCreateButton_API_Operation_NVP/) to create a secure button (pass BUTTONCODE=ENCRYPTED) using node.js. Secure buttons do not expose the form variables, so the client would never have access to the RETURNURL which is where your secret file is at, so there is no way they can attempt to download it. If they did find some way to decrypt the button, it would have taken them much longer than your 48 hour expiration. Either way, I doubt (no offense intended) users would be this interested in your product.

There are more ways to do this without storing user credentials on your server, but no way to do this without storing some type of data (see: code) on your server.

Comment: I know the sites you are referring to and it's definitely a step or two up from that :).  You are on to something though.  Because I'm new to all of this and want it simple I was thinking about having a page describing the tool with a full sample on it.  If they choose to buy it click the paypal button and pay.  Once paid get redirected back to this page.

Do you think the Encrypted Websites Payments API is the way to go there?

Comment: So the tool is not something they download, but an HTML page they can access? -- If simply having a unique ID that allows access to a page would work for your business case, EncryptedWebsitePayments API (or Express Checkout API) would definitely let you hide that return URL from the buyer so they are only directed to the correct page after paying.

Comment: But they could provide that URL to other people.. so you would definitely want to make sure you could make the page expire after 1 access, or after X time.. If your users say "hey, I access the page but then my browser died and I didnt get to download the file" then you can verify payment in PayPal.. ask for their transaction ID and date. buyer and payer transaction IDs are different, but that should be enough to verify payment.

Comment: Ok cool.  Thanks @SgtPooki. Yes the page is hosted on my server with some javascript so the client can be interactive.  The idea is to provide them with access to this tool/form after they have paid. Once paid I want them to have access for a day or two. I'm not super concerned if they abuse the link for the day they have access. By your description it sounds like I should be able to get this done with PayPal.  Just need to tinker with it.

Comment: Yep, the RETURN URL functionality of paypal will send them right to your page as soon as they're done paying :)

Comment: And you think encrypted website payments API will create a tokenized URL?  Or do I have to build my own routine on the server side for that?

Comment: You have to create your own tokenized URL and ensure that url leads to the correct file. You set the RETURNURL for the paypal button to that URL.

Comment: So the question I have is how do you create that tokenized URL?

Comment: This ~looks~ like what I'm looking for.  Going to have to give it a whirl. https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-singleItemPayment-curl-etc/

Comment: Express Checkout (EC) does the same thing, just requires API calls to make the payment, and you will still need your own URL